# How to use one controller for both forms?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I've been running into several problems, while codding my first app using JavaFX. Here is the one of these:
I have one form which contains two forms. F.e.:

```
<GridPain>
    <fx:include source="Form1.fxml"/>
    <fx:include source="Form2.fxml"/>
</GridPain>
```

I've made a reference one the same controller inside each form (Form1.fxml, Form2.fxml) Form1 contains TextField:

```
<TextField fx:id="name"/>
```

Form2 contains button:

```
<Button fx:id="sayYourName"/>
```

I include button and text field in my controller:

```
public class MyController implements Initializable  {
    @FXML
    private Button sayYourName;
    @FXML
    private TextField name;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        if (name == null) {
            System.out.println(true);
        }

        if (sayYourName == null) {
            System.out.println(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Tell me please, why I've got

```
true
true
```

And how can I use one controller for both forms?

Comment: Don't. Use a different controller for each FXML file.

Comment: The reason you get the output you see is that the first instance of the controller (the one created for `Form1.fxml`) has `name` initialized to a `TextField` and `sayYourName` not initialized (i.e. `null`), so the second `if(...)`  block gets executed. In the controller instance created for `Form2.fxml`, `sayYourName` is not `null` but `name` is `null`, so the first `if(...)` block is executed. It is probably clearer if you just do `System.out.println(name);` `System.out.println(sayYourName);` instead of the `if(...)` statements.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this when I started, so here is a suggestion that may help you. Have two separate forms each with their own controller. You have a 'master' form where the two forms get loaded into. First load a form like this:

```
private VBox view1;
private Pane view2;

private View1Controller view1Controller;
private View2Controller view2Controller;

try {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("form1.fxml"));
    view1 = (Pane) loader.load();
    view1Controller = loader.<View1Controller>getController();            
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Similar for form2.

Your rootView will also be loaded the same way.

Once rootView is loaded you can add both forms to the rootView. E.g.

```
rootView.getChildren().add(view1);
rootView.getChildren().add(view2);
```

Now you have two forms with two controllers. If one controller needs to talk to the other your can set a reference something like:

```
view2Controller.init(view1Controller);
```

and in view2Controller you have:

```
View1Controller view1Controller;

public void init(View1Controller controller){
    this.view1Controller = controller;
}
```

After this view2Controller can call methods in view1Controller like this:

```
view1Controller.xxxxx();
```

Depending on the complexity of you app, it's probably a good idea to have one 'master' controller (like an MVC or MVP structure) and use the others as 'slave' controllers. Controllers can talk to each other by passing a reference as shown above.

Note: this was edited after the comment below from James

Comment: This is a good suggestion, but why did you make everything `static`?

Comment: In a past life, memory was a main concern (no pun!) so I tended to use static a lot. But in this case there's no need. I don't think it does any harm though as I generally load in Main.java and I don't refer back to Main after that. Perhaps there is better reason to not make them static?

Comment: An object takes the same amount of memory no matter whether the reference you have to it is `static` or not. When your boss comes to your office and asks you to refactor the application so that the user can open multiple copies at once, say in different windows or tabs, you'll be completely stuck if you made things static for no reason. Beginners should regard `static` as an advanced topic, aside from simply declaring constants.